# Azure ARM templates - Linked templates with VSTS Git

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I have a have a main ARM template that refers to couple of linked ARM templates. Each of the ARM templates are hosted in their own private VSTS Git repo. When deploying the main template the ARM engine will need to authenticate to the private VSTS git repo. I have seen examples of how this can be achieved when the content is stored in github. Is it possible to do the same thing with VSTS git and if yes how?

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

its not achievable without hacks, be it github, vsts whatever. if you need authentication its not possible without hacks.

Comment: Well in github, you can get the raw content url and attach a token to azuredeploy.json uri. Is this a hack? How the access token is secured is mostl probably with CI CD tools.

Comment: you can do that only with azure storage, to my knowledge. ARM engine is only capable of url authorization. it won't pass any username, tokens, etc

Comment: Exactly. So my question is if there is a way to construct a vsts git repo url with the access token in the url itself. So ex - you can do this with github. I am trying to find if there is a way to do the same with vsts git repo. In bitbucket this is how it would be https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/blah/raw/xxx/azuredeploy.json?accesstoken=gblahblah

Comment: example for github?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<GitHub User Name>/<Repository>/<branch>/<path to the file>&githubaccesstoken=<GitHub Person Access Token>

Answer (score 0):

There is the workaround for deploying ARM template with private Repository by using Azure Function app:

[Deploying ARM Templates with Artifacts Located in a Private GitHub Repository](http://blog.tyang.org/2017/05/19/deploying-arm-templates-with-artifacts-located-in-a-private-github-repository/)

BTW: I can access the file by using this link below through Postman, but can’t access through internet browser.

```
https://test:[accesstoken]@[account].VisualStudio.com/DefaultCollection/[project]/_apis/git/repositories/[repository]/items?scopePath=/helloword.json&api-version=1.0&$format=Text
```

Comment: Thank you let me try the above one. What is the "test". is the Personal Access token name?

Comment: @HariSubramaniam It can be anything if you are using access token, so test is ok. (Note: with that URL, it can't access the source through Linked template too, just can be access from Postman tool)