# Azure Resource Group Deployment with ARM linked template from non public GIT

Tags: git, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-devops-rest-api

**Can I use -TemplateUri parameter from New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment pointing to non public GIT resource (not GitHub)?**

**Is there any other way to use GIT as source for ARM templates and linked templates (without using azure storage or azure function hack - described below)?**

Additional info for above questions:

I'm trying to provision some resources using VSTS build pipeline, however for sake of this question I will limit it to powershell New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment
command.

Working scenario (without linked template)

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName RG -TemplateFile path_to_local_template/template.json
```

If `template.json` is without linked/nested templates, all works properly. When I add a linked template, it starts to fail due to unknown location of the linked template file. That is perfectly clear - because linked template is on my local machine (or on agent machine) and it is not visible from Resource Manager.

I decided to use -templateUri parameter (template.json is in Git repo)

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName RG -TemplateUri https://<org>.visualstudio.com/<proj>/_apis/git/repositories/..../items?path=.../template.json
```

[Git Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/items/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) link to the resource works perfectly via browser if I'm logged in (so it is correct).

When executing above command I get (XXX is exactly the same as the templateUri provided):

```
##[error]Failed to download the file. URL: XXX . Error: 302: Found
```

Again, kinda obvious - due to authorization redirect.

I found a nice [blog post from Tao Yang](https://blog.tyang.org/2017/05/19/deploying-arm-templates-with-artifacts-located-in-a-private-github-repository/) about doing the same thing, but for GitHub. He had to hack it using Aruze functions as a proxy for getting template json. I would like to avoid proxy in my solution.

Another approach is to use [Azure Storage and SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) for that - So copying templates from Git to azure storage and then accessing it from via URL using SAS Token. I would like to avoid using azure storage too.

I tried using public token for accessing `template.json` via git api, as mentioned in [one of the answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644690/azure-arm-templates-linked-templates-with-vsts-git), so URL to template looks like that:

```
https://name:<token>@<org>.visualstudio.com/<proj>/_apis/git/repositories/..../items?path=.../template.json
```

However I still get 302 error.

Of course, if I get the teplateUri working, then the next step is to get it working with linked template, which should be also fetched from Git.

Comment: whats the question? if git api allows links like that it should work. if not - it shouldnt. any form of auth except sas token is not supported. it should work if its embedded into the url, though

Comment: Hi, question is in bold.

Comment: i can read, but its not a question or rather has nothing to do with azure. the i've already posted the answer

Comment: Can you share the detailed logs for that task?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT error is added into question: "Failed to download the file. URL: ''. Error: 302: Found"

Comment: Could you get the file programming through PowerShell before call New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I could, but then linked template will not work. It will behave exactly the same as local file.